# azure-sdk-for-c-arduino ESP32 with SIM7600CE unable to send MQTT's

Tags: azure, mqtt, esp32, azure-iot-hub, lte

This is the example code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/tree/main/examples/Azure_IoT_Central_ESP32

I changed the sinc time function to sinc with gps time.
And i activate the network with the following AT-commands

```
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,\"IP\",\"smartsites.t-mobile\
AT+CSOCKSETPN=1
AT+NETOPEN
AT+IPADDR
AT+NETOPEN?
AT+CSQ
```

CSQ is always above 19 and network is connected.
The Wifi connection checks I commend out.
All is good till `azure_iot_do_work(&azure_iot);` line is called.
It sends the code to the file AzureIot.cpp
around line 307 the statment

`if (result != 0){ // || azure_iot->config->mqtt_client_interface.mqtt_client_init( &mqtt_client_config, &azure_iot->mqtt_client_handle) != 0){`

Is called after that it gives massage

```
assertion "Invalid mbox" failed: file "/home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/api/tcpip.c", line 267, function: tcpip_callback_with_block

abort() was called at PC 0x400dc14b on core 1

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400850d8:0x3ffb3d80 0x40085355:0x3ffb3da0 0x400dc14b:0x3ffb3dc0 0x400ff74a:0x3ffb3df0 0x400ff709:0x3ffb3e10 0x400f792d:0x3ffb3e50 0x40111a91:0x3ffb3ea0 0x40111ad4:0x3ffb3ef0 0x40111fb9:0x3ffb3f30 0x40112223:0x3ffb3f60 0x400f76cc:0x3ffb3f90 0x4012bc71:0x3ffb3fb0 0x400ee37a:0x3ffb3fd0 0x40086366:0x3ffb4000
```

It has something to do with init of the MQTT but I can't figure out what exacly is the problem.
Does some one know this problem?

Used difrand AT command to mabey activade MQTT but don't know if that is needed. It didn't work.

**After a few days I came to the conclusion that it is not possible to directly connect SIM7600 with IoT Hub / Central.**
You need to use AT+CMQTTCONNECT but to establish a connection to Azure you need to enter the username and password only azure accepts a specific format that is too long for the AT+CMQTTCONNECT commend. And can only take 12 char for user and pass well the needed is at least 45 char.
Source : [link](https://www.elementzonline.com/downloads/SIM7600/SIM7500_SIM7600%20Series_MQTT_ATC_V1.01.pdf)

If you find a solution for a direct connection to Azure let me know.

Comment: Use  direct connection to Azure [telemetry](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-develop/quickstart-devkit-microchip-atsame54-xpro.md)